# How to get edittext items from listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-custom-view, listadapter

I'm new to android and I'm working on small tasks. I got struck with something and I really need help with this.

I have a custom listview which contains a textview, an edittext and again a textview and below that I have a button. My problem is that when I click on that button I need to get the edittext values from all the list items.

I don't know how to achieve this, so I kindly request everyone to help me with this issue.
Below is my code that I used for custom listview.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private final String[] items;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_row, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text_Product);
        TextView textPrice = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.text_Price);
        EditText edit_Quantity = (EditText)rowView.findViewById(R.id.edit_Quantity);
        textView.setText(items[position]);

        String s = items[position];

        if (s.equals("Samsung")) {
            textPrice.setText("10000");
            edit_Quantity.setText("0");
        } else if (s.equals("Apple")) {
            textPrice.setText("15000");
            edit_Quantity.setText("1");
        } else if (s.equals("Nokia")) {
            textPrice.setText("8000");
            edit_Quantity.setText("2");
        } else {
            textPrice.setText("12000");
            edit_Quantity.setText("3");
        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

I need the edittext values to be stored in a list when I click on the button. Please help me with this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908670/how-to-show-value-of-edittext-in-listview-each-time-on-button-click-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Just add a list in your code like

```
List <String> editcontent= new ArrayList<String>();
```

and now when you are writting items to the edit text.
also make an entry to the list view

```
    editcontent.add(0); .// for samsung (ref. to your code)

if (s.equals("Samsung")) {
            textPrice.setText("10000");
            edit_Quantity.setText("0");
            editcontent.add(0);
        } else if (s.equals("Apple")) {
            textPrice.setText("15000");
            edit_Quantity.setText("1");
            editcontent.add(1);
        } else if (s.equals("Nokia")) {
            textPrice.setText("8000");
            edit_Quantity.setText("2");
            editcontent.add(2);
        } else {
            textPrice.setText("12000");
            edit_Quantity.setText("3");
            editcontent.add(3);
        }
```

then you can fetch the record you want from this list
ex:

```
editcontent.get(position);
```